# Propositions in haskell

Tags: function, haskell, scope

I am trying to implement function **mapProp**.

```
mapProp :: (Proposition -> Proposition) -> Proposition -> Proposition
```

So when it finds proposition field as below

[image]

function is applied to the first argument *'a'*, then to the second argument *'b'* and then it is summed up by ***And 'a' 'b'***.
When no proposition field found - applies **f**.

So far I had the description for

```
data Proposition =  Const Bool
                | Var String
                | And Proposition Proposition
                | Or Proposition Proposition
                | Not Proposition
```

Below is my attempt to implement the function, but it gives me an error that *variable is not in scope* of Proposition. Any hints?

```
mapProp f prop | prop == (Const a) || (Var a) || (Not a) = f a 
               | prop == (And a b) || (Or a b) = And ((f a) (f b))
               | otherwise = f prop
```

Comment: Use pattern matching, not `==`. You can find some example in [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#algebraic-data-types).

Answer (score 0):

In a function definition like:

```
mapProp f prop | prop == Const a = f a
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                this is a guard
```

the part `| prop == Const a` is a "guard".  It's a boolean expression that must be *evaluated* and yield true for the definition to match.

Let me emphasize again that the guard expression needs to be **evaluated**.  You can't use a guard as a kind of "equation solver" to match `prop` to `Const a` and solve for the variable `a`.

What's happening here is that Haskell is evaluating the expression `prop == Const a`.  It knows the value of `prop`, since that was matched by the pattern before the guard, but when it tries to evaluate `Const a`, the variable `a` hasn't been defined, so you get the error message "Variable not in scope: a :: Bool".

In order to "solve" for `a`, you need to use the pattern part of the definition itself, not a guard.  So, you'd need to write the above definition as:

```
mapProp f (Const a) = f a
          ^^^^^^^^^
           pattern
```

Unfortunately, a consequence of this is that you can't use the handy syntax of boolean operators like `||` to combine a bunch of matching patterns on one line.  The most straightforward way of writing your function definition is to use multiple lines, one for each pattern, even though the right-hand side is redundant for some cases:

```
mapProp f (Const a) = f a
mapProp f (Var a)   = f a
mapProp f (Not a)   = f a
mapProp (And a b) = And ((f a) (f b))
mapProp (Or a b)  = And ((f a) (f b))
mapProp f prop = f prop   -- the default case
```